# Perspective Scrolling Effect (Three Instances)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this perspective scrolling effect and I want to make three instances of it.
Each of the instances ultimately will have different content. And each instance would be in a modal popup.

The modal popup should be triggered by a link and they're closeable by an 'x' in the corner, and the key ESC. Ideally i would like to avoid bootstrap.

CSS

```js
const dom = {
    container: document.getElementById('container'),
    perspective: document.getElementById('perspective'),
    zoom: document.getElementById('zoom')
};

const totalScrollDistance = 10000; // Scroll distance to reach max zoom
const maxZoomDistance = 40000; // Maximum depth of images, based on what you've set in CSS
let looping = false;

dom.container.style.height = `${totalScrollDistance}px`;

window.addEventListener('scroll', update);

function update() {
    // Check if we are waiting for a frame to render
    if (!looping) {
        looping = true;
        raf(zoom);
    }
}

function zoom() {
    const rect = dom.container.getBoundingClientRect(); // Get bounding rect of container, .top is relative to top of viewport

    if (rect.top <= 0 && rect.top > -rect.height) { // Update zoom only when container is in viewport 
        dom.perspective.classList.add('perspective--is-fixed');

        const scrollPos = -rect.top; // Get scroll position relative to zoom container
        const progress = scrollPos / (totalScrollDistance - window.innerHeight); // Turn this into a number between 0 and 1 (0 is when top of zoom container is at top of viewport, 1 is when bottom of zoom container is at bottom of viewport)

        dom.zoom.style.transform = `translate3d(0, 0, ${progress * maxZoomDistance}px)`; // Apply transform
    } else {
        dom.perspective.classList.remove('perspective--is-fixed');
    }

    looping = false;
}

// Runs callback on next available animation frame
function raf(cb) {
    const raf = window.requestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame || window.oRequestAnimationFrame || function (cb) { window.setTimeout(cb, 1000 / 60); };

    raf.call(window, () => {
        return cb();
    });
}
```

```css
html,body,address,blockquote,div,form,fieldset,caption,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,hr,ul,li,ol,ul,dl,dt,dd,table,tr,td,th,p,img{margin:0;padding:0}
html{width:100%;height:100%;overflow-x:hidden}
body{font-family:'Times';position:relative;width:100%;min-height:100%;color:#272935;padding:0;margin:0}
body::before,body::after{display:flex;justify-content:center;width:100%;height:25vh;color:#000}
html{overflow:none;overflow-x:hidden;scroll-behavior:smooth;scrollbar-width:none}
::-webkit-scrollbar{width:0;background:transparent}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb{background:red}
*,:before,:after{box-sizing:border-box}
.container{position:relative;overflow:hidden}
.perspective{width:100vw;height:100vh;background:none;position:fixed;perspective:200px}
.perspective--is-fixed{position:fixed;top:0;left:0}
.caption{color:#000;font-size:1rem;text-align:center;padding-top:20px}
p{color:#000;text-align:left;}
.zoom{width:100%;height:100%;transform-style:preserve-3d}
video{position:relative;width:45%;box-shadow:26px 33px 121px 0 rgba(119,0,0,0.4)}
img{position:relative;width:45%;box-shadow:26px 33px 121px 0 rgba(119,0,0,0.4)}
.right{float:right}
.image{position:absolute;text-align:center}
.image:nth-child(1){width:100vw;height:100vh;transform:translate3d(1vw,1vh,-200px)}
.image:nth-child(2){width:100vw;height:100vw;transform:translate3d(2vw,6vh,-1700px)}
.image:nth-child(3){width:100vw;height:100vw;transform:translate3d(0vw,6vh,-3723px)}
.image:nth-child(4){width:100vw;height:100vw;transform:translate3d(7vw,13vh,-4835px)}
.image:nth-child(5){width:100vw;height:100vw;transform:translate3d(10vw,-1vh,-6791px)}
```

```html
<div class="container" id="container">
  <div class="perspective" id="perspective">
    <div class="zoom" id="zoom">

      <!--Content01-->
      <div class="image"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/700x600/4a1bf5/ffffff" />
        <div class="caption">One</div>
      </div>

      <!--Content02-->
      <div class="image"><video autoplay loop muted>
          <source src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/87/Schlossbergbahn.webm" type="video/webm"></video>
        <div class="caption">Two</div>
      </div>

      <!--Content02-->
      <div class="image"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/700x600/4a1bf5/ffffff" />
        <div class="caption">Three</div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```